# UIViewController IBOutlets are nil

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, xib

I have an UIViewController class with two labels and a UIImageView set as IBOutlets, and I have this outlets connected in my xib, I have double checked they are connected properly, however when I check the their value in the debugger they are 0x0 so I cant change them programatically. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong.

Heres the header file of my code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface PlateDetailViewController : UIViewController {

     IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
     IBOutlet UILabel *price;
     IBOutlet UILabel *description;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIImageView *image;

@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *price;

@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *description;


@end
```

Comment: Tell us where in the programs execution you are when you enter the debugger? I.e., which method on which class are you in? Is this a crash? A breakpoint? What?

Comment: Im creating a PlateDetailViewController with alloc initWithNibName from view A, it is in this view that all the properties of the PlateDetailViewController that I crated in interface builder are nil, this doesn't  make my app crash, but I cant add an image to the imageView of the PlateDetailViewController from view A

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your outlets won't get set until the view controller's view is actually instantiated, which in your case is probably happening shortly *after* `initWithNibName:bundle:`—at which point they'll still be nil. Any setup you do that involves those outlets should be happening in your view controller's `-viewDidLoad` method.